Multiply two pandas dataframe by index
I have two long dataframes like so:
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1],
                    [2, 1],
                    [3, 1],
                    [2, 1],
                    [2, 2],
                    [3, 2],
                    [5, 3]], columns=['value', 'id'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4])

The first column of df1 act as the value, while the second column is an ID column.
What I want to do is multiply df1 by df2, the first value of each ID is multiplied by the first value of df2, the second value multiplied by the second and so on. So for instance, for id=1, we would get [1x1=1, 2x2=4, 3x3=9, 4x2=8], for id=2, we would get [2x1=2, 3x2=6],... It is guaranteed that the values for each ID does not appear more than the length of df2, and ultimately the result would be something like
1
4
9
8
2
6
5


@ScaryWombat It's the first value with id=3, so it would be multiplied with the first value in df2, so it would be 5x1=5

code
out = df1.groupby('id').cumcount().map(df2[0]).mul(df1['value'])

out
0    1
1    4
2    9
3    8
4    2
5    6
6    5
dtype: int64

@wjandrea's comment:
Enumerate each group of ids, use those to index into df2[0], then multiply.

Nice! It'd help to add a quick explanation though, like "Enumerate each group of ids, use those to index into df2[0], then multiply." By all means use that if you want.

Try this:
df2 = df2.rename(columns={0: "M"})
df1['mindex'] = df1.groupby('id').cumcount().values
df1['multiplier'] = df2.M.values[df1['mindex']]
df1['product'] = df1['value'] * df1['multiplier']
df1 

Or a one-liner:
# if you don't want to rename the column in df2
df1['value'] * df2[0].values[df1.groupby('id').cumcount().values]

Explanation
For column df1: You need a mechanism to count the number of occurrences (with a -1 shift, starting from 0, 1, 2, ...) of the ids: the four 1s would be then 0, 1, 2, 3; the next two occurrences of the 2s in the id column will be 0, 1 and final 3 will be just 0.
The benefit of these counts (shifted by -1) is that they can now act as the index of the values we get from df2.
We calculate these indices with df1.groupby('id').cumcount().values, which returns an array of [0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]. This is stored in the column mindex.
Finally when we feed these indices inside df2.M (we have renamed the column 0 to M), it returns the desired set of multipliers.
Multiplying the columns value and multiplier yields the result in the product column.
Result:




value
id
mindex
multiplier
product




0
1
1
0
1
1


1
2
1
1
2
4


2
3
1
2
3
9


3
2
1
3
4
8


4
2
2
0
1
2


5
3
2
1
2
6


6
5
3
0
1
5




You don't need to add multiplier to the df... Are you just using it for illustration?

Why bother renaming df2[0]? You could just as well do df2[0].values...

Yes, it's just used here for illustration. The whole thing can be done in a single row.

@wjandrea Naming column should be preferably done with letters rather than numbers. If I were the OP, I would name that column something more meaningful. I know df2[0].values can be used. I wanted to show that named columns have the advantage of using df2.M notation.

Fair enough. I don't use or recommend dot notation myself since it has so many drawbacks (see the warning under Attribute access).
